# Disable reverse DNS lookup in SSH Client

Tags: ssh, dns, centos

I was trying to avoid the reverse dns lookup by the ssh client. But I can not use the `UseDNS` option since it requires file modification to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which I'm not privileged to do.

Tried with `-u0` (`$ssh -u0 user@192.168.10.225 -vvv`) but the client complaints with `ssh: illegal option -- u`

Using Centos 6.2.
Is there any way out?

Comment: I don't think you can do this, it would not be very secure to let the client tell the server to do less verification on the client

Comment: what happens if you just 'ssh user@192.168.10.225 -vvv'? What exactly does not work? If nothing else helps you could make an entry in '/etc/hosts' for that IP. Or use the 'VerifyHostKeyDNS' Client-Option